# What is the maximum voltage of a Lithium Ion Battery

Tags: batteries, safety, lithium-ion, charging

My question is about the maximum charge voltage of a Lithium-Ion cell.

I have charged my battery pack with 8.4V (the maximum voltage). The pack is a Samsung ICR18650-26F. The pack has a smart controller with a maximum voltage of 8.5V. This is 4.25V per cell.

I read about this that exceeding 8.5V can degrade the lifetime of the pack. However, the manufacturer don't clarify this detail.

My question: Will this voltage damage the cells or this within the tolerance range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasheet I'm reading says those batteries (like almost all other Li-Ion battery packs) have a charging voltage of 4.2V +/- 0.05V per cell. So two cell pack would be 8.4V plus or minus 0.1V.

So yes, it is within the tolerance range as specified by the manufacturer. But bear in mind you are supposed to aim for 8.4V! So if you aim for 8.5V and you are the smallest bit off then you will be out of tolerance.

My guess is that the manufacturer of your charger is simply saying the same thing as the manufacturer of your batteries: 8.5V is the maximum value in the range that the charger is specified to output.

Simple answer is that this seems fine to me.